# R: Paste and combine multiple outputs from ifelse after grepl of patterns in list

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, paste, grepl

I tried to search posts similar like my issue but couldn't find any.

My goal is to combine cells of column ***name*** from df1 **(if multiple, separate by "_")** to a new column ***pasteHere*** in df2, by matching string (I use grepl) in df1$order to df2$ref.

It's a big dataframe so I included for loop to loop each row.

I am not sure if the error comes from the looping, *grepl*, or is it simply not possible to combine multiple items in this case?

First, dummy data:

```
## dummy data
df1 <- data.frame(ggplot2::msleep[c(1:10),c(1:5)]) 
df2 <- data.frame(ref = unique(df1$order), pasteHere = NA)

## how the dfs look like:
> df1
                         name       genus  vore        order conservation
1                     Cheetah    Acinonyx carni    Carnivora           lc
2                  Owl monkey       Aotus  omni     Primates         <NA>
3             Mountain beaver  Aplodontia herbi     Rodentia           nt
4  Greater short-tailed shrew     Blarina  omni Soricomorpha           lc
5                         Cow         Bos herbi Artiodactyla domesticated
6            Three-toed sloth    Bradypus herbi       Pilosa         <NA>
7           Northern fur seal Callorhinus carni    Carnivora           vu
8                Vesper mouse     Calomys  <NA>     Rodentia         <NA>
9                         Dog       Canis carni    Carnivora domesticated
10                   Roe deer   Capreolus herbi Artiodactyla           lc

> df2
           ref pasteHere
1    Carnivora        NA
2     Primates        NA
3     Rodentia        NA
4 Soricomorpha        NA
5 Artiodactyla        NA
6       Pilosa        NA
```

You can see *Canivora*, *Rodentia*, and *Artiodactyla* appeared three, two, and two times in df1$order, respectively.

Now, by matching df1$order to df2$ref, I want to paste df1$name to df2$pasteHere and combine those with multiple occurrences using "_". I am still inexperienced in using R for-loop.

Below is my failed attempt:

```
## my failed attempt: 
for(i in 1:length(df2$ref)){
  
  for(j in df2$ref){
    df2$pasteHere[i] <- ifelse(grepl(df2$ref==j, df1$order), paste(df1$name, collapse="_"), "NA")
  }

}
```

gives below warnings from *grepl*:

```
> warnings()[1:5]
Warning messages:
1: In grepl(df2$ref == j, df1$order) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In df2$pasteHere[i] <- ifelse(grepl(df2$ref == j, df1$order),  ... :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
3: In grepl(df2$ref == j, df1$order) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
4: In df2$pasteHere[i] <- ifelse(grepl(df2$ref == j, df1$order),  ... :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
5: In grepl(df2$ref == j, df1$order) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

What I want my final dataframe to be like:

```
> final_df
           ref                     pasteHere
1    Carnivora Cheetah_Northern fur seal_Dog
2     Primates                    Owl monkey
3     Rodentia  Mountain beaver_Vesper mouse
4 Soricomorpha    Greater short-tailed shrew
5 Artiodactyla                  Cow_Roe deer
6       Pilosa              Three-toed sloth
```

I am unsure is the issue comes from pasting multiple items though. Please advice. Other solutions will be fine too! :)

**---------------------------UPDATE:-----------------------------**

**Update reason:**

**Above dummy data was too simplified for my intended question, below updated new dummy data which fitted more to my current situation:**

```
df1 <- data.frame(ggplot2::msleep[c(1:10),c(1,4)]) 
order_longString <-  list(c("eeny", "Carnivora", "meeny"),
                         c("Primates", "miny", "moe"),
                         c("catch","a","tiger","Rodentia"),
                         c("by","the","toe","Soricomorpha","If"),
                         c("he","Artiodactyla","hollers"),
                         c("let","Pilosa"),
                         c("him","go","Carnivora"),
                         c("eenie","Rodentia","minie","money","more"),
                         c("Carnivora","catch"),
                         c("a","piggy","Artiodactyla","by","the","snout"))
df1$order_longString <- order_longString
df2 = data.frame(ref = unique(df1$order), pasteHere = NA)


## Updated df looks like this:
> df1
                         name        order                       order_longString
1                     Cheetah    Carnivora                 eeny, Carnivora, meeny
2                  Owl monkey     Primates                    Primates, miny, moe
3             Mountain beaver     Rodentia              catch, a, tiger, Rodentia
4  Greater short-tailed shrew Soricomorpha         by, the, toe, Soricomorpha, If
5                         Cow Artiodactyla              he, Artiodactyla, hollers
6            Three-toed sloth       Pilosa                            let, Pilosa
7           Northern fur seal    Carnivora                     him, go, Carnivora
8                Vesper mouse     Rodentia    eenie, Rodentia, minie, money, more
9                         Dog    Carnivora                       Carnivora, catch
10                   Roe deer Artiodactyla a, piggy, Artiodactyla, by, the, snout

> df2 # remain the same
           ref pasteHere
1    Carnivora        NA
2     Primates        NA
3     Rodentia        NA
4 Soricomorpha        NA
5 Artiodactyla        NA
6       Pilosa        NA
```

Now, let's look at df1$order_longString instead. It's a long with unequal numbers of strings and each character separated by ",". I need to match df2$ref pattern to strings in df1$order_longString. It is the reason why I used *grepl*.

Then, as above, once the pattern is matched, followed by pasting df1$name of the row with to df2$pasteHere and combine those with multiple occurrences using "_".

Hope I made this clear!

Answer (score 1):

Do you even need the second df in this scenario?

**I suggest to use data.table:**

```
library(data.table)

df1 = data.table(ggplot2::msleep[c(1:10),c(1:5)]) 

df_final = df1[, .(pasteHere = str_c(name, collapse = "_")), by=order]
```

**Output:**

```
> df_final
          order                     pasteHere
1:    Carnivora Cheetah_Northern fur seal_Dog
2:     Primates                    Owl monkey
3:     Rodentia  Mountain beaver_Vesper mouse
4: Soricomorpha    Greater short-tailed shrew
5: Artiodactyla                  Cow_Roe deer
6:       Pilosa              Three-toed sloth
```

**If you need the combined df, you could do it like:**

```
library(data.table)

df1 = data.table(ggplot2::msleep[c(1:10),c(1:5)]) 
df2 = data.table(ref = unique(df1$order), pasteHere = NA)

df1 = df1[, .(pasteHere = str_c(name, collapse = "_")), by=order]

df_final = merge(df2[, c("ref")], df1, by.x="ref", by.y="order")
```

**Output:**

```
            ref                     pasteHere
1: Artiodactyla                  Cow_Roe deer
2:    Carnivora Cheetah_Northern fur seal_Dog
3:       Pilosa              Three-toed sloth
4:     Primates                    Owl monkey
5:     Rodentia  Mountain beaver_Vesper mouse
6: Soricomorpha    Greater short-tailed shrew
```

Comment: Thank you for replying so soon! I realised I am making a big mistake by using a over simplified dummy data. This wasn't exactly what I intended and I need to make the dummy data more similar to my situation. Do you suggest me to use 'Answer Your Question' button below to repost my question, or edit the post straightaway? Sorry I am too new in this website

Comment: just create an "Update:" or "Edit:" block in your initial post :-)